# $ionicPush.register not registering devices

Tags: ionic-framework

I have created a very simple app to try and get the ionic push notifications working with ionic.io service. I created a blank ionic 1 app. Added the ionic cloud plugin. added the phoegap-plugin-push plugin. Here is my app.js code :

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic','ionic.cloud'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
      // for form inputs)
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

      // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
      // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
      // a much nicer keyboard experience.
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

    .config(function($ionicCloudProvider) {
        $ionicCloudProvider.init({
            "core": {
                "app_id": "XXXXXXX"
            },
            "push": {
                "sender_id": "XXXXXXXXXX",
                "pluginConfig": {
                    "ios": {
                        "badge": true,
                        "sound": true
                    },
                    "android": {
                        "iconColor": "#343434"
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    })

    .run(function($ionicPlatform,$ionicPush) {
        $ionicPush.register().then(function(t) {
            return $ionicPush.saveToken(t);
        }).then(function(t) {
            console.log('Token saved:', t.token);
        });


    })

;
```

When I log the response I get this message:

Ionic Push: saved push token: [object Object] ionic.cloud.min.js:1
Token saved: cIiJ-TlvXyM:APA91bGKZZi_4XlfMLyY2C7-lwFiLYbqYjk7_4MwtQU7TyqHvLeKgdMPVuMOYpGshkmenunaF6Re1fKky6lP1aBK-Ik9NZJqp2XCIFFo8EAP6Cytn-cY7cRREAK5x69Ji3P-ZFpqNKw4

But when I look at my app on the ionic.io dashboard, I got to users and there are no users registered.

Any ideads?

Comment: did you find any solution?